# Mapping enum subtypes in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I'm developing a Java application using **Java 6** and **Hibernate 3.6.9** library. I want to create an enum which is closely related to a specific class, so I want to define it as part of that class:

```
package org.mycompany.container;

public class Container{

    public enum ContainerType{
        SMALL,MEDIUM,BIG
    }

    private ContainerType _ContainerType;

    private Integer _Id;

    //Getter and setters

}
```

Then I want to map my container class in an Hibernate configuration file (I don't use annotations). So I have this xml piece (the package of the class is specified at the beginning of the hibernate-mapping file):

```
<class name="Container" table="tcontainer">
    <id name="_Id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="_ContainerType" column="container_type">
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">org.mycompany.container.Container.ContainerType</param>
            <param name="type">12</param>
        </type>
    </property>
</class>
```

However, Hibernate doesn't seem to recognize the **ContainerType** class and I get a *ClassNotFoundException*. I have done this several times having the *enum* as a separate class.

Any solution? Pool your ideas.

Comment: do you have both the hbm files and your class in the same project? Because it could be a dependency issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
org.mycompany.container.Container$ContainerType
```

Comment: and this "I have done this several times having the enum as a separate class." didn't work?

Comment: @fGo, of course it works, but for design concepts I want to keep the enum inside the class.